# Why is background not being covered completely

Tags: html, css

This is my css for the background, but the thing is that there is still a 4px gap from all edges in the background. Whats wrong?

```
#header-color {
    background:transparent;
    background: #cccccc; /* old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cccccc 24%, #eeeeee 100%); /* firefox */

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(24%,#cccccc), color-stop(100%,#eeeeee)); /* webkit */

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#eeeeee',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-position:top;
}
```

Comment: off-topic: I suggest using [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) for IE, as it will allow you to use standard CSS gradients rather than those horrible `filter` styles.

Comment: do you have margins or a border set on that element anywhere else? (i.e. inline, or via a class). I don't believe backgrounds apply to margins, and obviously borders are styled on their own. Padding, however, does accept the element's background style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of element is `header-color`? You might need to add:

```
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```

If your header is at the top of the page, you might need to remove the margin and padding of the body, like this:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: so should I just add it in the css?

Comment: Since you are new, you might not realize this: if my answer answered your question, you should click the checkmark next to it to indicate that it is *the* answer. :-)

Comment: I'll do that exactly in seven mins.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the user agent stylesheet's default `margin` on `body`:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers used to have own style definitions. If you include some kind of reset in your css, your background will be covered. Some options:

- http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
- http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/
- http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-reset/

Example reset css:

```
/* ----------------------------
simple reset
---------------------------- */

html, body, ul, ol, li, form, fieldset, legend
{
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p { margin-top: 0; }
fieldset,img { border: 0; }

legend { color: #000; }
li { list-style: none; }
sup { vertical-align: text-top; }
sub { vertical-align: text-bottom; }
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td
{
    text-align: left; vertical-align: top; font-weight: normal;
}
input, textarea, select
{
    font-size: 110%; line-height: 1.1;
}
abbr, acronym
{
    border-bottom: .1em dotted; cursor: help;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you've given us is insufficient to be able to diagnose the problem accurately. There's nothing inherent in the CSS code you've provided that would cause a 4px gap, and you haven't told us anything about the context of the element, so we can't see what else around it might be causing the gap either.

However, my guess is that the 4px gap is likely to be the default padding/margin around the edge of the page body.

This is a bit of a throw-back to the old days but it's still there, so if you want your page content to flow right to the edge of the window, you need to clear out these edges, like so:

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

There are a number of other little quirks in the default styles which can catch you out (especially as some have cross-browser differences), so it is a good idea to have a 'reset' stylesheet. There are a number of them available, but you might want to try this one: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Adding this stylesheet to your site will ensure that all those little layout quirks are dealt with.

Hope that helps.